# Symfony config component, setArgument with yaml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I'am trying to convert this php config

```
$container->register('framework', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel')
->setArguments(array(new Reference('dispatcher'), new Reference('resolver')));
```

Into yaml syntax, i already did well with dispatcher, and resolver but cant understand now how to pass arguments to HttpKernel constructor, i ve tried already

```
framework:
    class:    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
    arguments:  ["dispatcher", "resolver"]


framework:
    class:    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
    arguments:  [dispatcher, resolver]
```

But i am getting error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface, string given in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, must be

```
framework:
    class:    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
    arguments:  ["@dispatcher", "@resolver"]
```

pay attention to **@**